# Проблемы с вертской background окрашивает не всё

Tags: html, css

Поставил `background` для класса `header`, но по бокам появляется белый фон: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.header {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background-color: #f6f2f2;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #313030;
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 90px;
}

.menu ul {
  margin-left: 360px;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #d7d7d7;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="float-left">
    <h1>Our strong organisation</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed sapien turpis. Duis finibus, purus vehicula efficitur imperdiet, turpis tellus rhoncus dui, finibus rutrum purus elit at leo. Nunc elit lacus, mollis sit amet suscipit sed, egestas
      nec metus. Praesent sit amet ultricies eros. Cras erat ipsum, cursus id lectus quis, accumsan placerat turpis. Donec luctus mattis quam quis sagittis. Nam ut lectus mauris. Curabitur porttitor congue metus vitae fringilla. Maecenas sapien arcu,
      venenatis eget libero ac, finibus dapibus quam.
    </p>
    <button>Contact Us</button>
  </div>
  <video width="400" height="300" controls="controls">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: `margin-top: 200px;` у `.menu` оттягивает всю страницу вниз, `.header { overflow: hidden; }`

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых всегда старайтесь показать код в вопросе, во-вторых следите за дефолтными отступами тегов. Необходимо сбросить отступы у `body` , далее заметил там какой то отступ для `.menu margin-top: 200px;` она вам нужна ? И самая главная проблема, вы не сбросили отступы для `ul` меню, т.е `.menu ul`

> UPD

Для выравнивания уберите `margin-left: 360px;` и установите `text-align:center;` для `.menu`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background-color: #f6f2f2;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #313030;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #d7d7d7;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="float-left">
    <h1>Our strong organisation</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed sapien turpis. Duis finibus, purus vehicula efficitur imperdiet, turpis tellus rhoncus dui, finibus rutrum purus elit at leo. Nunc elit lacus, mollis sit amet suscipit sed, egestas
      nec metus. Praesent sit amet ultricies eros. Cras erat ipsum, cursus id lectus quis, accumsan placerat turpis. Donec luctus mattis quam quis sagittis. Nam ut lectus mauris. Curabitur porttitor congue metus vitae fringilla. Maecenas sapien arcu,
      venenatis eget libero ac, finibus dapibus quam.
    </p>
    <button>Contact Us</button>
  </div>
  <video width="400" height="300" controls="controls">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ты ставишь фон для div блока. Поэтому у тебя есть отступы. Тебе надо прописать для body тот же класс, тогда всё закрасит в нужный цвет.

Comment: то что Вы написали является скорее советом, чем полноценным ответом на вопрос. Это уместнее писать в комментариях (они будут доступны при достижении Вами рейтинга >= 50).  В вопросе есть вся необходимая для конкретного ответа информация.